# autoupdate of model id in store on sync

Tags: extjs

I am creating a new model instance:

```
component.record = Ext.create('MyApp.model.HolidayModel',{id:0});
Ext.getStore("HolidayStore").add(component.record);
Ext.getStore("HolidayStore").sync();
```

`id` is the default idProperty in ExtJS, and I didn't change that.

During sync, the following is sent to the server:

```
{"id":0,"cls":"blue","country":"Republik Österreich","enddatelist":["15.08.2014", "15.08.2015",…],"name":"Mariä Himmelfahrt","startdatelist":["15.08.2014", "15.08.2015",…],"statelist":[]}
```

and the following is answered by the server:

```
{"success":true,"data":[{"id":30,"name":"Mariä Himmelfahrt","country":"Republik Österreich","startdatelist":["15.08.2014", "15.08.2015",…],"enddatelist":["15.08.2014", "15.08.2015",…],"statelist":[],"cls":"blue"}],"Debug":[],"Message":"","Caption":""}
```

which should tell ExtJS that the id of the posted model instance has to be updated, right?

(The store's reader has root:"data" set.)

Yet, the record still has `id:0` - so, if I

- insert the first  model instance
- sync (only the first is posted to the server)
- insert a second model instance
- sync (only the second is posted to the server)

then the first instance is no longer shown in the grid that HolidayStore is bound to.

Any idea as to why? Is it because the new model instance isn't send in an array, but the model is returned in an array?

Comment: it's strange logic... seems you need {id: fromRecord.getId()}

Comment: Where should I take `fromRecord` from, when there is no record. I am creating a NEW model instance (a NEW record, to be saved in the database. And the database is assigning an auto-increment id to the record).

Comment: Then, what do you want? Client send to server id = 0, server insert this record to your database(for example) and return data to client. You need to check server side,what id of new record saved in database.

Comment: Please read! It IS returned. I send to the server `id:0`and server returns `id:30`. Just that ExtJS does not update the id in the store, and I don't know why.

Comment: Something like this - Ext.getStore("HolidayStore").sync({
                     callback: function () {
                        component.record.load(newIdFromResponse)    
                     },
                     scope: this
                 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to quote myself:

Is it because the new model instance isn't send in an array, but the model is returned in an array?

and add that exactly this turned out to be the reason.

I now always send it as an array (`allowSingle:false`), and the id is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try `component.record = Ext.create('MyApp.model.HolidayModel',{});`

maybe ExtJS doesn't update fields which are already set.